# How to parse a response from a httpRequest in Java for the following API?

Tags: java, api, httprequest

I am using the [this API](https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api) to create my food aplication.

I am trying to parse the response of the following HTTPREQUEST as a JSONObject. The problem is that even though I get a status code of 200, my JSONObject remains empty.

HTTPRequest: `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${YOUR_APP_ID}&app_key=${YOUR_APP_KEY}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free`

Code:

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("response code is " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    return myResponse;
  }
```

I think it's a lot of work for you to take the time to get developer credentials just for helping me. I appreciate the help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you look at the content of `response`? You print the `responseCode` but not the content.

Comment: I printed it in another function.

Comment: How can you print `response` in another function? It only exists as a local variable in that method. Note, I'm saying `response`, not `myResponse`, i.e. the raw text *before* you parse to JSON.